# SQL - Get databases size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have implemented Blob storage for sharepoint. The code below works and I want to make sure it's counting the filestream on the drive for the blobs as well.

```
SELECT [Database Name] = DB_NAME(database_id),
       [Type] = CASE WHEN Type_Desc = 'ROWS' THEN 'Data File(s)'
                     WHEN Type_Desc = 'LOG'  THEN 'Log File(s)'
                     ELSE Type_Desc END,
       [Size in MB] = CAST( ((SUM(Size)* 8) / 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(18,2) )
FROM   sys.master_files
-- Uncomment if you need to query for a particular database
-- WHERE      database_id = DB_ID(‘Database Name’)
GROUP BY      GROUPING SETS
              (
                     (DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc),
                     (DB_NAME(database_id))
              )
ORDER BY      DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc DESC
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try one of these SQL scripts.

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name


--- SQL2005
select o.name
, reservedpages = sum(a.total_pages)
, usedpages = sum(a.used_pages)
, pages = sum(case when a.type <> 1 then a.used_pages
when p.index_id < 2 then a.data_pages else 0 end)
, SUM(a.used_pages)*8096 AS 'Size(B)'
, rows = sum(case when (p.index_id < 2) and (a.type = 1) then p.rows else 0 end)
from sys.objects o
join sys.partitions p on p.object_id = o.object_id
join sys.allocation_units a on p.partition_id = a.container_id
where o.type = 'U'
group by o.name
order by 3 desc --biggest tables first
```

In addition, here are a couple links that will give you some more ideas.

http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/88859/sql-server-2008-r2-table-sizes.html

http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Listing%20all%20tables%20in%20a%20database%20and%20their%20row%20counts%20and%20sizes.aspx

Comment: Thanks ryguy7272. I will test the script and let you know. I appreciate it.